# How many days left on an Apple Developer membership would I need to submit an app update for review?

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect, appstore-approval

I've got about ten days left on my Apple Developer Program membership.

I want to get an update on my app in before the membership expires, so I don't need to renew my membership straight away.

When can I submit my app and still expect it to get past?

Do I need to submit it with enough time left to get through the processing period?

Can I submit an updated version of my app with a day left and expect it to get through the processing period and be updated on the app store for people to update without any issues?

Comment: If your membership expires then any apps you have in the app store will be removed anyway.

Comment: @Paulw11 would not people who already downloaded it be able to get the updates though?

Comment: As long as they update before your membership expires

Answer (score 1):

As per apple

> If your Apple Developer Program membership expires, your apps will no
>   longer be available for download and you will not be able to submit
>   new apps or updates. You will lose access to pre-release software,
>   Certificates, Identifiers & Profiles, and Technical Support Incidents.
>   However, your apps will still function for users who have already
>   installed or downloaded them, and you will still have access to iTunes
>   Connect and free development resources.

[Source](https://developer.apple.com/support/renewal//)

Comment: Would they still process it if I had submitted it before expiration? Even if it was, let's say, one day?

Comment: After expiration, apps will no longer be available for download. So it doesn't matter they will process it or no. You will not able to use iTunes Connect to see your app processing status after expiration.